# Plotting colores areas in a leaflet maps

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, spatial

How would I add some heatmaps plates to a leaflet map?

Say I have some spatial econometrics model and I want to plot prediction to a leaflet map like in the picure attached[![enter image description here][1]][1]

For now I have a simple code in `R` that goes like this:

`m <- leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.OceanBasemap") %>% addCircles(lat=df$latitude,lng=df$longitude, radius = 100, color = "green", opacity = 0.45, weight = 7) %>% 
addCircles(lat=df2$latitude,lng=df2$longitude, radius = 100, color = "#FC4E07", opacity = 0.45, weight = 7)`

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked. Otherwise, "how do I do this thing in general?" is too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can do it using the **addHeatmap()** function. See [this](https://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-heat) or [this](https://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-heatmap) tutorial.

Another option is to perform your calculations and then plot the resulting raster file. See [the documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html)

Comment: You might want to revisit [answer]. The question is too broad to give a specific answer to (no code, no data, nothing to debug), and answers that are just links are prone to breaking over time